# macOS esc key doesn't work on my macOS mojave

Tags: macos, macos-mojave

Issue: the ESC key doesn't work

Given I opened some dialogue, if I hit my ESC key, the dialogue didn't closed.

Expected behavior: Before updating the mojave (I used high serria), I can close the dialogue by hitting my ESC key.

For example, I can't close the confirmation dialogue by hitting ESC:
[image]

Here is my computer info:

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: Exactly what do you mean it "doesn't work"? What are you expecting it to do, in what situation, and what does it do instead?

Comment: Given I opened some dialogue, if I hit my ESC key, the dialogue didn't closed.

Expected behavior: Before updating the mojave (I used high serria), I can close the dialogue by hitting my ESC key.

Comment: Yes yes, Exactly!

Comment: You can try your "Esc" key with opening the Terminal, then entering the command `cat`, then pressing "Esc" should give you the output `^[` (press "ctrl-c" to stop). Is this working for you?

Comment: sadly No, it's not responding without any output

Comment: To dismiss a dialog, you can also press "cmd + ." If your "Esc" key is not responding, I would advice getting the Utility https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/ It is very easy to remap any key you don't use to the Esc key (Caps is a great candidate). There's also a convenient "Karabiner EventViewer" to test all your keys.

Comment: It's helpful!   However, this problem is gone after I restarted my computer...